# What is the correct なさる masu form?

Tags: verbs, conjugations, politeness

Im getting two different conjugations of なさる masu form from different sites

some say なさります
some say なさいます

I know that the conjugation rule for godan verbs ending in る is to convert the る into り and add ます

I also know that なさる is the honorific form of する which is an irregular verb, so I am truly stumped as to what the proper spelling would be.